# Azure DevOps Pipeline log, marks the number 1 as ***

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am at a bit of a loss here, have a very simple yaml pipeline.
No variables are defined for the pipeline.
A few variables are defined inside the yaml, but none are marked secret.

I have tried deleting the pipeline and recreating it - same problem.

I get this output: (As you can see in line 4, it says *** instead of 1)

[image: 1s are marked ***]

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you have a secret variable with that value. Or a task that generates a secret output variable with that value. It's also possible you're referencing a YAML template or a variable library that contains the value.

Comment: Yeah, I think so too, problem is i have neither :/

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem, but with the letter "a". I found the culprit. In my key vault I had one entry "SubscriptionKey" set to "a" as a dummy value, because I didn't have a real value available yet.
Key vault secret: SubscriptionKey

Then I included it in my pipeline by including it in a Library VariableGroup which was connected to my key vault. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#create-a-variable-group)
Library VariableGroup "DevKeyVaultVariableGroup": SubscriptionKey

In my pipeline I included the group like this

```
variables:
- group: DevKeyVaultVariableGroup
- name: SubscriptionKey
  value: $(SubscriptionKey)
```

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-variable-group)

After I included that variable from the key vault, all 'a' s were turned into ***. I fixed it by removing the variable. If I need to bring it back, I'll make sure it is a real value and not a dummy value.